# Trie, prefix for phonenumbers

Tags: c++, trie

I a building a program that takes phone numbers as input. It should then check if there already exists a phone number which is a prefix in our new number.
Example:

```
Input:
555 //This is okay
5556888 //This is not okay because 555 is a registered number
556888 //this is okay
5568889 // Not okay
```

Hope you understand what I'm getting at.

I have implemented two functions:

**Contains**
That should check if the number or prefixes already exist.

```
bool PrefixStringSet::contains(string s)
{
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[s[i] - '0'];
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Insert**

```
bool PrefixStringSet::insert(string s)
{
    if(contains(s) == true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        int number = (int)s[i] - (int)'0';
        if(temp->children[number] == NULL)
        {
            temp->children[number] = new TrieNode;
            temp = temp->children[number];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As it stands now contains only check's if the number has already been registered. I can't figure out a good way to check if the prefix is already a number.
Should I implement it in contains or maybe in the insert function(Maybe have a loop go trough each prefix, starting with the first number?)

Any help appreciated.

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    PrefixStringSet Phonenumber;
   int HowManyPhoneNumbers;
   cin >> HowManyPhoneNumbers;
   for(int i = 0 ; i<HowManyPhoneNumbers ; i++)
   {

       string temp;
       cin >> temp;
       if(Phonenumber.insert(temp) == true)
       {
           cout << "Yes" << endl;
       }
       else
       {
           cout << "NO" <<endl;
       }

   }
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**
Insert:

```
    bool PrefixStringSet::insert(string s)
    {
       if(contains(s) == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        NodePtr temp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            int number = (int)s[i] - (int)'0';
            if(temp->children[number] == NULL)
            {
                temp->children[number] = new TrieNode;
            }
            temp = temp->children[number];
        }
        return true;
    }

Contains:
bool PrefixStringSet::contains(string s)
{
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(temp->is_leaf())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[s[i] - '0'];
    }
    return true;
}

input:
 911
YES
9111 /Not working
Yes
91 //Working
NO
```

**edit2:**

```
bool PrefixStringSet::contains(string s)
{
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(temp->is_leaf())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (temp !=root &&  temp->is_leaf())
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[s[i] - '0'];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Usually the signature for methods like this is `const string& s` to avoid having to copy the string for use within your functions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're going through all the trouble of computing a trie (homework?) because a simple [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of allowed prefixes would be a lot faster to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PrefixStringSet::contains(string s)`

```
    if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Instead of returning `false` directly, you should check whether `temp` has any non-NULL child.
That is,

```
    if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
    {
        return (temp != root && temp->is_leaf());
    }
```

Because if `temp` has no child at all, then the string `s`'s prefix already exists.
*Edit:* Check `temp != root` to avoid being stuck at empty trie.

The most efficient implementation of `TrieNode::hasAnyChild()` depends on how `TrieNode::children` was stored, which you didn't show in the question statement. If your trie only accepts decimal digits, then simply go through all children should be good enough.

By the way, in `PrefixStringSet::insert(string s)`

```
    int number = (int)s[i] - (int)'0';
    if(temp->children[number] == NULL)
    {
        temp->children[number] = new TrieNode;
        temp = temp->children[number];
    }
```

The line `temp = temp->children[number];` should be moved after the end of `if` block since you need to move `temp` one step further no matter you created a new node or not.

Comment: I should be able to say.. return temp->isleaf() instead right?

Comment: Sure. They mean the same.

Comment: What am I doing exactly by returning temp->isleaf()

Comment: @user3265963 Just like `if (temp->isleaf()) return true; else return false;`. Not sure if this answered your question.

Comment: @user3265963 You should return true when temp->isleaf() is `true`.

Comment: If I return true in if(temp->isleaf()) I get NO for every input. Even the first one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48289/discussion-between-timrau-and-user3265963)

Answer (score 2):

In a standard Trie, you should have another field in your Node struct to indicate whether it indicates a word.

```
bool PrefixStringSet::contains(string s)
{
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(temp->isWord)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(temp->children[s[i] - '0'] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[s[i] - '0'];
    }
    return true;
}

bool PrefixStringSet::insert(string s)
{
    if(contains(s) == true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    NodePtr temp = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        int number = (int)s[i] - (int)'0';
        if(temp->children[number] == NULL)
        {
            temp->children[number] = new TrieNode;
        }
        temp = temp->children[number];
    }
    temp->isWord = true;
    return true;
}
```

However, in your problem, only a **LEAF** node indicates a existing word, because you don't allow any number to be a prefix of another number in this Trie.

So you can check whether a Node is a leaf node by iterating its children as @timaru says. But it's not very efficient.

Comment: I made the adjustments you suggested and it is half working now. It only works when you input shorter string than exists. Check the update in my OP.